# Bootstrap modal loading remote content generating 2 requests

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap modal to load data remotely, for some reason this request is going to the server twice and then it is messing up the view of the modal.

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-middle modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a data-toggle="modal" id="@series.Id" href="@Url.Action("GetEpisodes")?id=@series.Id&title=@(Url.Encode(series.Title))" data-target="#myModal">@series.Title</a>
```

**Modal Content Once Loaded**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="episodeModal">@Model.SeasonTitle</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @foreach (var kvp in Model.EpisodeViewModels)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-grid">
                @*<h4 class="panel-title">Season @kvp.Key</h4>*@

                <h4 class="col-md-1 panel-title-small text-left"></h4>
                <h4 class="col-md-6 panel-title-small text-center">Title</h4>
                <h4 class="col-md-2 panel-title-small text-center">Downloaded</h4>
                <h4 class="col-md-2 panel-title-small text-center">Air Date</h4>
                <h4 class="col-md-1 panel-title-small text-left">Search</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <small>Season @kvp.Key</small>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                @foreach (var ep in kvp.Value)
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1 text-center">@ep.EpisodeNumber</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">@ep.Title</div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">@Html.Raw(ep.HasFileIcon)</div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">@ep.AirDate.ToShortDateString()</div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 text-center"><i class="fa @FontAwesome.Search"><a class="episodeId" href="#" id="@ep.ID"></a></i></div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript to handle loading multiple remote data**

```
$(function() {
    $("a[data-target=#myModal]").click(function (ev) {
        console.log("clicked");
        ev.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");

        // load the url and show modal on success
        $("#myModal .modal-body").load(target, function() { 
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
            $('#myModal').modal('handleUpdate');
        });
    });
});
```

*Note the problem happens without the above JS code.*

How can I stop this from happening and for it to only generate 1 request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you manually add event handler for modal you don't want the `data-` attribute set on element that does the same thing automatically on page load.

Remove the `data-toggle` attribute from element.

The bootstrap.js library looks for those attributes and assigns event handlers accordingly

Comment: Wow... Well that was easy. Thank you for your help. I'll accept the answer in 8 mins.

Comment: `data-target` will also be redundant as the 2 attributes are combined to create event handler and component target